# Legend is not working properly in Python

Tags: python, graph, legend

[image]    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np 
    import xlrd
    import xlwt
    import pandas as pd

```
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('Scatter plot.xlsx')

sh1 = wb.sheet_by_name('T180')
sh2=wb.sheet_by_name("T181")
sh3=wb.sheet_by_name("T182")
sh4=wb.sheet_by_name("T183")
sh5=wb.sheet_by_name("T189")

x= np.array([sh1.col_values(1, start_rowx=51, end_rowx=301)])
y= np.array([sh1.col_values(2, start_rowx=51, end_rowx=315)])

x1= np.array(sh2.col_values(1, start_rowx=50, end_rowx=298))
y1= np.array(sh2.col_values(2, start_rowx=50, end_rowx=298))

plt.style.use('ggplot')
fn ="C:\Users\M15-1478\Desktop\python\Scatter plot.xlsx"
sheetname = 'T181'
df = pd.read_excel(fn, sheetname=sheetname, skiprows=47,    parse_cols='B:C').dropna(how='any')
df.ix[df.eval('0 <= GrvX <= 1000'), 'GrvX'] -= 150
df.ix[df.eval('1000 < GrvX <= 2000'), 'GrvX'] -= 50
df.ix[df.eval('2000 < GrvX'), 'GrvX'] -= 30

# customize Y-values
df.ix[df.eval('0 <= GrvY <= 1000'), 'GrvY'] += 30

print df
df.plot(x='GrvX', y='GrvY',  linestyle='no line', marker="o",  label="Corrected T182")
plt.plot(x,y, "gs", label="T181")
plt.plot(x1,y1, "bx", label="T182")
plt.legend(loc=0)
plt.show()
```

The legend is not showing properly except the first one ("corrected T182"). I tried it many way. How can I solve this problem? I attach my problematic picture here. I also attach the data file for your conveninece. Thanks in advance. [Data file](http://www.filedropper.com/scatterplot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found if I use Panda to read the xls file then there is no problem with legend. It is working quite nicely[image]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np 
    import pandas as pd
    import math
    import xlwt
    import xlrd

```
x_180=df_180.iloc[:,7]
y_180=df_180.iloc[:,8]

x_181=df_181.iloc[:,7]
y_181=df_181.iloc[:,8]

x_182=df_182.iloc[:,7]
y_182=df_182.iloc[:,8]

x_183=df_183.iloc[:,7]
y_183=df_183.iloc[:,8]

plt.plot(x_180,y_180,"ro", label="T180")
plt.plot(x_181,y_181,"gs", label="T181")
plt.plot(x_182,y_182,"bx", label="T182")

plt.xlabel("x (micron)", size ="18",color ="m")
plt.ylabel("y (micron)", size ="18",color ="m")
plt.title("Scatter plot of two adjacent detector surfaces after translation", size ="18",color ="m")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```